# Image shows properly with .show() but saves with artifacts

Tags: image, python-2.7, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have unpickled an image, and utilizing PIL when I use img.show() I can see the image in external viewer properly but when I try to save it using img.save() it is plagued by horizontal color artifacts. As img.show() is using bmp to temporarily save and show the file, I tried using img.save(filepath, "bmp") as well as other file formats. Other formats, such as jpg and png, totally corrupt the image, while bmp creates color artifacts. I checked the documentation for PIL but it was not helpful. What method can I use to save the image I see properly?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing it.

Comment: try to save image using cv2.imwrite(); maybe this works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries, it turns out instead of:

```
with open("img.bmp", 'w') as f:
    image.save(f)
```

opening the file with the binary attribute "b" added solves the issue. Like this:

```
with open("img.bmp", 'wb') as f:
    image.save(f)
```